# Choosing schema.org type for a travel / tour

Tags: schema.org

I’m trying to choose schema.org format that best suits multi-day travel event, like tour.

It has the following attributes:

- Start time, e.g. May 29, 2018
- End time, e.g. June 7, 2018
- Duration, e.g. 7 days
- Start place (location that can be a different city / country)
- End place (location)
- Price, e.g. $99
- Rating

Ideally I would like to benefit from rich snippets. 
Not sure if `product` or `event` are suitable for this: product is said to 
describe a physical product, and event seems to me to have a duration within single day.

I can’t find other suitable formats in rich snippets though. Does it make sense to provide another schema? What are the benefits then?

Comment: It's an event... product is a physical or digital item.

Comment: There is no SEO benefit to schema except rich snippets.

Answer (score 3):

Apply markup for type **[TravelAction](http://schema.org/TravelAction)**. For example:

```
<main vocab=https://schema.org/ typeof=TravelAction>
<h1 property=name>Your travel tour to Z</h1>
<p property=description>zzzzzz</p>
<p><time property=startTime datetime=2018-05-29></time></p>
<p><time property=endTime datetime=2018-06-07></time></p>
<section property=fromLocation typeof=Place>
<h2>Start from</h2>
<div property=address typeof=PostalAddress>
<p property=streetAddress>The street address.</p>
<p property=postalCode>555 55</p>
<p property=addressRegion>The region</p>
<p property=addressLocality>The locality</p>
<p property=addressCountry>The country (You can also provide the two-letter ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country code https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1 exempel:<meta property=addressCountry content=SE>)</p>
</div>
</section>
<section property=toLocation typeof=Place>
<h2>End to</h2>
<div property=address typeof=PostalAddress>
<p property=addressLocality>The locality</p>
<p property=addressCountry>The country<meta property=addressCountry content=AR> (You can also provide the two-letter ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country code https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1 )</p>
</div></section>
<section property=potentialAction typeof=TradeAction>
<h2 property=name>The Price</h2>
<p property=priceSpecification typeof=PriceSpecification>$<meta property=priceCurrency content=USD>99<meta property=price content=99></p>
</section></main>
```

Check out this markup on the **[Google tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool)** ++ info about **[Currency code of ISO 4217](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217)**.

Answer (score 3):

This probably won't help you now, over a year on. But hopefully, it can help someone else! http://schema.org/TouristTrip

Comment: I've tried http://schema.org/TouristTrip but never gotten it to succeed. GSC acts like it does not even exist on my page. Does it work for you Robb?

Answer (score 1):

*Look, up in the sky! It's a bird! It's a plane! It's an event!*

Generally a product is associated with a physical item or digital product. Concerts, tours, gigs and other events should use the [schema event](http://schema.org/Event) because not only is it more correct, the results can appear in glorious fashion within the search results.

> [Google Developers: Article about Schema Event](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/event)
>
> Mark up your organized events so that users can discover events
>   through Google Search results and other Google products like Google
>   Maps.
>
> You can add all types of events through markup — from performances by
>   famous artists, to a neighborhood salsa class. Adding markup to your
>   events makes it easier for users to discover and attend your event.

*Limited capacity or sale of online tickets? no problem, Schema Ticket*

Tickets schema go hand and hand with Event, example of JSON-LD which is more flexible than inline Schema would look something like this:

> [SOURCE](http://schema.org/Ticket)
>
> ```
> <script type="application/ld+json">
> {
>   "@context": "http://schema.org",
>   "@type": "EventReservation",
>   "reservationId": "E123456789",
>   "reservationStatus": "http://schema.org/ReservationConfirmed",
>   "underName": {
>     "@type": "Person",
>     "name": "John Smith"
>   },
>   "reservationFor": {
>     "@type": "Event",
>     "name": "Foo Fighters Concert",
>     "startDate": "2017-03-06T19:30:00-08:00",
>     "location": {
>       "@type": "Place",
>       "name": "AT&T Park",
>       "address": {
>         "@type": "PostalAddress",
>         "streetAddress": "24 Willie Mays Plaza",
>         "addressLocality": "San Francisco",
>         "addressRegion": "CA",
>         "postalCode": "94107",
>         "addressCountry": "US"
>       }
>     }
>   },
>   "reservedTicket": {
>     "@type": "Ticket",
>     "ticketNumber": "abc123",
>     "ticketToken": "qrCode:AB34",
>     "ticketedSeat": {
>       "@type": "Seat",
>       "seatRow": "A",
>       "seatNumber": "12",
>       "seatSection": "101"
>     }
>   }
> }
> </script>
> ```

If you sell online tickets then you should try to attach ticket schema to the Event

*Example of an Sports Event (exact search)*

[image: Example of Events in Search Results]

*Example of Music Events in London (broad this week search)*
[image: Example of Music Events in London]

*OMG!? TBH Schema doesn't work and sucks IMO...*

It should be noted that just having Schema doesn't assure that your event, product or anything else is shown in Rich Snippet fashion, its common for Google to ignore some events, products and services.

Comment: This is wrong. Events and trips are 2 different things, and google explicitly states under content guidelines: "Avoid marking non-events as events: Don’t promote non-event products or services such as "Trip package: San Diego/LA, 7 nights" as events." -> https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/event

Answer (score 1):

Try this schema maybe it will suit your needs.

https://schema.org/Trip

```
    <div class="tourist-trip-wrapper">
<h1>
 Australia and New Zealand
</h1>
<p>
This trip is modeled as two distinct Tourist Trips using the subTrip property.
</p>
<div class="has-part-wrapper">
<div>
  <h2>
    Australia
  </h2>
  <p>
    This is a trip on its own.
  </p>
</div>
<div>
  <h2>
    New Zealand
  </h2>
  <p>
    This is another trip nested inside the main one.
  </p>
</div>
```

and there is a Travel Agency schema

https://schema.org/TravelAgency